# Is there a book for writing console/terminal applications using C++?

Tags: c++, linux, unix

I am interested in writing terminal applications like wget, mutt and so on using C++ on unix/linux. Can you recommend a good book about this subject?

Answer (score 4):

Maybe this can help you:

[Advance linux programming](http://www.advancedlinuxprogramming.com/alp-folder/alp-ch08-linux-system-calls.pdf)

Comment: great to see others using the same resources

Comment: The book is a bit old, but very useful. Most of the stuff it describes is still relevant today, but be sure to check the man pages.

Comment: This answer is just a link. There should, at the very least, be a few words of comment on what is good or not so good about the book, and how well you know it.

Answer (score 1):

Linux systems programming, along with inter-process communication, threading, shared memory and sockets is explained in this free online book called [Advanced Linux Programming.](http://www.advancedlinuxprogramming.com/)
And here's another book [An Introduction to GCC](http://www.network-theory.co.uk/gcc/intro/) that explains the compiler and linker along with simple C and C++ examples.

Comment: For terminal applications, learning and using `ncurses` could be useful.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to point out that, for example, `wget` isn't what I'd call a "terminal program". It is more of a network program. Network programming is an art in itself!

I agree that the provide links are very good. But when I see the term console / terminal program, I'm thinking more of something that does a little bit of cursor movement, like emacs, vi, linux's menuconfigu and the like. In which case, if you want an easy life, `ncurses` is a good library to add to your collection of "things you understand".

Comment: Mats Petersson, I used console/terminal program because I am not interested in gui apps/books. All over the net I see people use the same meaning.
For example: http://www.cyberciti.biz/open-source/best-terminal-applications-for-linux-unix-macosx/

Comment: This sounds more like a comment than an answer to me.